# Вопросы безопасности сайта

Tags: php

Привет всем, один мой сайт был взломан. Я уже восстановил его (файлы сайта и БД). Но вот в чем вопрос - как мне ограничить вход в админку только с определенного внешнего IP адреса? Решит ли это проблему безопасности? Защитит ли это сайт от будущих нападков кул хацкеров?

Answer (score 2):

> будующих

будущих

> Защитит ли это сайт от будующих нападков кул хацкеров?

Да, но придется каждый раз добавлять новый айпишник при появлении новой точки доступа. Сам айпишник подделать не проблема, но в этом случае ответ не придет к хацкающему, обычно так не заморачиваются. Плюс хакер должен знать разрешенный айпишник, что у него не получится без серьезной системы прослушки или физического доступа к серверу.

Тут либо через средства веб-сервера, например, htaccess (пример нагло утянут с инета, не гарантирую работоспособность):

```
<Files admin.php>
order allow,deny
allow from 127.0.0.1
deny from all
</Files>
```

Либо прямо в PHP проверять `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, в который записывается айпишник.

В любом случае вероятнее всего надо смотреть не админку, а точки загрузки файлов. Скорее всего просто загрузили исполняемый файл, который потом оказался внутри структуры сайта, что позволило вызвать его простым http-запросом.

Comment: В этом сайте нет возможности загружать файлы на сервер, так что этот вариант можно отбросить...

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, что сначала надо выяснить способ взлома и устранить его. Иначе все это борьба с ветряными мельницами.

Comment: Ну, тогда надо реально длинные пароли ставить, как всегда )  
Есть еще вероятность сломанной системы авторизации, тогда самым простым действительно будет разрешить доступ по конкретному айпишнику.

Comment: @vanchester вставки кода из file_get_contents и eval имеются, но встречаются довольно редко. Где можно прочитать на что их можно заменить, чтобы повысить безопасность?

Comment: @Fike скорее всего так и было - злоумышленники завладели аккаунтом администратора и изменили пароль, хотя пароль был далеко не 1234, а такой который подобрать практически невозможно. Может быть это была SQL инъекция?

Comment: @eprivalov1, есть такая вероятность.

Comment: @eprivalov1, способов может быть очень много. например,

 * подобран пароль (к ssh/rdp, к админке, к базе)
 * использована уязвимость CMS/Framework/любого плагина
 * использована уязвимость какого-то ПО на сервере
 * использована уязвимость непосредственно вашего кода (инъекции, загрузка файлов и т.д.)

Можно долго гадать, каким образом это было сделано, а нужно брать логи и все внимательно разбирать и все найденное вычищать. Иначе вы рискуете потратить время впустую и наткнуться на эту проблему еще раз.

Comment: Что касается указанных функций, то просто посмотрите, стояли они там изначально или нет. Если используете CMS, то просто обновите ее полностью, желательно с удалением всех файлов и новой их заливкой. Из своего опыта могу сказать, что даже через картинку (при некоторых комбинациях настроек и используемого ПО) можно выполнять код на сервере

Comment: SSH, CMS и Framework не использую. Движок самописный... Плюс есть класс, который проверяет содержимое всех глобальных массивов, таких как ГЕТ, ПОСТ, КУКИ и так далее..

Comment: @eprivalov1, системы контроля версий не используете? с их помощью легко увидеть "несанкционированные" изменения в коде и устранить их